# Adding UINavigationBar to UIView Programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationbar

I am trying to add a UINavigationBar to a UIView programmatically and having so success, and can't figure it out. I am trying to add it in my UIView subclass and it simply isn't showing up when I run my app.

Here is my code:

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, headerHeight)];
    [navBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [self addSubview:navBar];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(done:)];

    UINavigationItem *navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"categories"];
    [navItem setRightBarButtonItem:doneItem animated:YES];
    [navBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:navItem] animated:YES];
```

Comment: In what method do you have this code? I just tried it and it's working for me. Also, setting the backgroundColor won't have any effect. YOu have to use the "tintColor" property

Comment: Its called during the init method inside the `if (self)` statement. I don't see why that would stop it working, as I add other subviews here.

Comment: Well, it's very strange indeed as I just tried again to reproduce your scenario and it's working for me. I believe the problem may be that 'headerHeight' is set to 0.

Comment: Forgot to include that. Thats set to 44.0.

Comment: "barTintColor"property.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using the navigation controller from the first view I suggest this in your Appdelegate.m

```
 UIViewController *viewController = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController]; 
        self.window.rootViewController=navController;
```

but if you have a view which presents your new view that you want have a navbar use this for showing the new view:

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];
            UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController]; 
[self presentViewController:navigationcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

then you can add your navBarButtons in second view like below:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        UIBarButtonItem *btnAdd = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(btnAddGroupPressed)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=btnAdd;

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I have explained in the question. I am trying to add a UINavigationBar to a UIView. No controllers are part of this issue.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what's going on. Here is the code that I'm using to reproduce your issue:

The *.h file is empty

```
#import "STTestView.h"

@implementation STTestView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50)];
        navBar.barTintColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
        [self addSubview:navBar];

        UIBarButtonItem *doneItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(done:)];

        UINavigationItem *navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"categories"];
        [navItem setRightBarButtonItem:doneItem animated:YES];
        [navBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:navItem] animated:YES];

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)done:(id)sender {

}

@end
```

And this is what I'm getting:

[image]

Can you please:

1. Add the code for the whole `initWithFrame:` method?
2. Make sure that self.frame and headerHeight are in fact set correctly by the time your code runs?
3. Remember not to use the `backgroundColor` property but the `barTintColor` property

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I cannot tell you why, but I have experienced this same issue and I traced it to the `setBackgroundColor` method. To get around it I did:

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 44.0)];
UINavigationItem *titleItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"MyNavBar"];
NSDictionary *titleAttributesDictionary =  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                            [UIColor whiteColor],
                                            UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                            [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0],
                                            UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                            [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)],
                                            UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                            [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:20.0],
                                            UITextAttributeFont,
                                            nil];
navBar.titleTextAttributes = titleAttributesDictionary;
navBar.items = @[titleItem];
navBar.tintColor=[UIColor blueColor];
[self addSubview:navBar];
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you forgot "navBar.items = @[navItem];" as I dealt with similar issue:

```
    UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, headerHeight)];
    navBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self addSubview:navBar];//it is important point, otherwise, you can see only the area without any item

    UIBarButtonItem *doneItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(done:)];

    [navItem setRightBarButtonItem:doneItem animated:YES];
    [navBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:navItem] animated:YES];
```

Use these properties: "barTintColor" to get the color of the navigation bar background, and "tintColor" for the navigation items and bar button items.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xib instead of storyboard, then write these lines in AppDelegate:

```
UIViewController *viewControllerObj = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewControllerObj]; 
self.window.rootViewController=navController;
```

If you are using storyboard then its good to add NavigationController from Menu.